# how to close console window after form is closed

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

i have a console application project. it has gui (winforms) and console window which is used as debug console (application's run log).

now, if i have got debug disabled i hide console window with `ShowWindow` native call.

the problem is: after i close application window by pressin the `X` button or by quitting it (Application.Exit()) i have a zombie console process.

if i close console on the very begining by `Environment.Exit(0)` the form is not been showed.

i have tried to modify forms Closed event by adding there `Environment.Exit(0)`, but that did not work which means that there still remains a zombie console process.

how can i close console window on application exit?

Comment: Whenever you say that something 'did not work', you need to explain what you expected, and what happened differently from that.

Comment: Why not just have the winform up? how are you calling the gui from the console... are you calling the gui from the console.

Comment: And how do you know you have a 'zombie process' if the console is hidden? What do you mean by that?

Comment: 2Kendall Frey, i know that there is a zombie process because i'm monitoring process list. there is a cmd process, that was started by my application (i know it for sure, because before my application there was no cmd processes at all), and it remains after i quit. so, that i am calling zombie process. an orphaned process (this term is from *nix environment, have you heard about it?)

Comment: 2Serdalis, i can not have winform app, because i provide some command line functionality too. project was started as a console application. the gui was attached later. regarding how i calling gui: using Application.Run(new MyForm()).

Comment: @cheshie: You don't need to have it be a console app to run it from the command line. Try running Notepad from the command prompt.

Comment: 2Kendall Frey, i provide some command line functionality, beside gui mode functionality. so, there can be case, that gui not shown at all and all the work is done in console. i can not do that if i select Windows Application instead of Console application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a console application, the console will not "close" until the process terminates.  So you just simply need to close the form normally... assuming you "opened" it like you should.

To "open" the form, you need to *run* it.  Run it by calling [`Application.Run(Form)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx) (the same way you would initialize an actual form project). Since a console is allocated to your process, your form may write to `Console.Out` and you should see what you write.

Comment: worked. i just added Environment.Exit(0) at the very end of my Main function.